# Regression with a list of currencies

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, regression, prediction

I am using sklearn to predict currency values.  I have a dataframe with 38 columns that are the distinct currencies' rates, and 2761 rows which are daily observations.  When I use the basic linear regression, everything works quite well (I think).  However, when I try to use a GradientBoostingRegressor, I cannot get a valid shape, no matter what I try.

What's going on here?  Why is one okay and the other broken?  I have been scratching my head for days.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
n = 1

X = rates[:-n]
y = rates[n:]

reg = LinearRegression().fit(X,y)
```

^^^ This one produces good predictions.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
n = 1

X = rates[:-n]
y = rates[n:]

reg = GradientBoostingRegressor(loss="lad").fit(X,y)
```

^^^ This one has a "bad shape".  The shapes are the same: (2761, 38).

For reference:

```
rates.tail()
Out[2]: 
               AUD     BDT     BND     BRL  ...     THB     USD     VND     ZAR
2019-10-21  1054.5  18.109  1126.9  373.00  ...  50.692  1533.7  6.6086  103.81
2019-10-22  1053.6  18.127  1127.1  371.89  ...  50.645  1535.3  6.6170  104.43
2019-10-23  1050.3  18.126  1126.3  376.28  ...  50.658  1535.2  6.6154  104.67
2019-10-24  1047.5  18.107  1125.3  380.14  ...  50.672  1533.6  6.6092  104.93
2019-10-25  1046.1  18.080  1123.6  379.01  ...  50.734  1531.4  6.6007  104.54

[5 rows x 38 columns]
```

```
reg = GradientBoostingRegressor(loss="lad").fit(X,y)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-21ee59fafac1>", line 1, in <module>
    reg = GradientBoostingRegressor(loss="lad").fit(X,y)

  File "/home/s/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py", line 1450, in fit
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

  File "/home/s/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 760, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))

ValueError: bad input shape (2671, 38)
```

Comment: Can you include the exact error message? Are you sure your X and y are identical? I'm not familiar with the GradientBoostingRegressor in sklearn, but after a quick glance at the docs see no obvious reason why it wouldn't work like any estimator.

Comment: What is your `rates` precisely? Give me a piece of `rates`.

Comment: Thank you both... I agree that there should be no difference!  I'm really surprised.  My ultimate goal is to produce these predictions with intervals, so that users don't take the figures as law.

Answer (score 0):

I your target multi-dimensional? If not, I presume you meant to write

```
X = rates[:-n]
y = rates[-n:]
```

rather than

```
X = rates[:-n]
y = rates[n:]
```

Comment: In the first one, you saying "my features are all columns except for the last one, but target is the last one". In the second, you're saying "my features are all columns except for the last one, and my target is all columns from the first one onwards".

Comment: You're set `n=1`, so in doing `y = rates[n:]`, you're declaring that the target (`y`) is all columns of `rates` from `1` (the value of `n`) until the end. What you want to do is set the last column (`-1`) to be your target.